# Rearranging tree based on description of changes

Tags: algorithm, tree

We are working with a tree data structure. It does not have to be a binary tree. For example

```
  A
 /|\
B C D 
  |\
  D E
```

Let's say that the node (subtree) index is defined as an integer array where element at index i specifies nth node at level i. For example

```
[] - root node: A
[0] - first node at level 0: B
[1] - second node at level 0: C
[1, 1] - second node at level 1 of second node at level 0: E  
...
```

Now, say that we are given a description of how the tree should be changed in form of a list of moves. For example:

```
move(from: [1], to: [0])
move(from: [1, 0], to: [1])
move(from: [2], to: [1, 0, 0])
...
```

I. e. make node (subtree) at index [1] in the original tree end up at index [0] in the final tree. Make node (subtree) at index [1, 0] in the original tree end up at index [1] in the final tree.

Note that from index refers to the original tree, while to index refers to the final tree - after rearrangement is done. This means that given list of moves does not represent operations we can perform one after another. The order in that list is not important.

Now, how does one get a list of sequential operations from that description so that applying those operations in order on the original tree will give us the final tree? We can assume the description of changes is valid.

I've got to the point where I have it working if moves are unrelated, that is when there are no moves that move from a subtree of an already moved subtree or that move to an already moved subtree. I'm struggling with those cases. Just offsetting the indices is not enough and for some combination of moves the order is relevant.

I there maybe a known algorithm for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, there isn't a pre-made, ready-to-use algorithm for it. But it's definitely something you can do by yourself if you put your mind to it.

Comment: I updated the question with the paragraph on where I am now. I'm sure I can solve it eventually, I was hoping to get some hints or advices.

Comment: Do you have some code?